# Images don't load in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Demo: http://www.simpsoncrazy.com/characters/poster2
(Using Map Hilight plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/maphilight)

When you click a quadrant of the image, it should zoom in on that image, however in IE8 (regular and compat mode) the "zoomed" images never load. Also on the top-left segment the right arrow appears on the left.

I've looked at Firebug and IE Dev Tools but they seem largely the same apart from differing opacity definitions (IE uses filters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I messed around with this, and I think I found the problem in the CSS... just remove the `display:none;` from here:

```
#imagemap .map {
    position: absolute;
}
```

I have no idea why IE doesn't like it there.

Edit: LOL and UGH... I just looked at the front page of that site... there's a newer bigger poster LOL. All that work * smack forehead *

Comment: Excellent that seems to work! Yeah it's kinda funny about the poster, I had this project in mind for several years. The new poster looks pretty rubbish though, to be honest. :/

Answer (score 1):

Try putting filter value in quotes

```
filter: Alpha('Opacity=0')
```